# how to delete child entries while getting the matched parents using mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, sh, mongoose-populate

I am using mongodb shell command, I can get the collection data using `db.collection.find(findQuery)`.

In my example, I have Books and Authors table and it is many to many associated between them.

Sample data on viewing from books table is(this data is viewing from postman),

```
{"authors": [
            {
                "id": "123",
                "name": "Sivakumar"
            },
            {
                "id": "124",
                "name": "Ram"
            }
        ],
        "id": "456",
        "title": "Believe Yourself"
}
```

I can delete author entry by `db.authors.remove({name:"Ram"})`. This deletes the Ram entry but I have to delete all authors entries which is associated to books using shell command. I didn't find any documentation for populate in shell command. How can I delete authors entries by using find and populate in mongo shell command.

Comment: You need to iterate `authors`, remove books and then remove author like this: `db.authors.find({name:"Ram"}).forEach(function(doc){db.books.remove({book:book_id});db.authors.remove(doc);})`

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your post/requirement - $unset removes a field from a document.

you can simply not project the author field into any results - so in terms of output it isn't there and does not involve any actual delete.

You can create a new collection using the existing collection and simply not include the authors field.

Comment: I want to delete my older records in mongodb, here i have to find the author associated to books and delete those authors and then delete books using shell command